# Regards & Regard

Tags: meaning

We ofter use "Regards" at the end of our e-mail. In one of my mail I mistakenly wrote "Regard"(without a "s") which my BOSS didn't like! My question is what is the difference between "Regards" & "Regard"?

Comment: Just so you know, I would think nothing of seeing that at the end of an email.  It would obviously be a typo and not a very serious one.

Comment: For "compliments", "greetings", "regards", "thanks", and "best wishes", it is really very stingy if you only give one of them. You should always give many; it doesn't cost you anything extra.

Comment: I wish you were my BOSS :) @Julia . I will always keep your suggestion in my mind..@Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regard** (*singular noun*) means a look, a gaze, an aspect; and by extension esteem or attention.
**Regards** (*plural noun*) means the wishes that express such esteem or respect.

Though grammatically either noun might work, in social convention only the plural noun is normally seen. It is an *informal* abbreviation of the phrase "with best regards" or similar phrases.

Comment: Social convention is not arbitrary. It arises from the deeper meaning of the word, used with  or without "s". There is a difference. Perhaps not grammatically, since they both function as nouns. But certainly in terms of denotation and connotation.

Answer (score 1):

Regard is just a misspelling - which is probably why your boss didn't like it.

"Regards" is short for "my best regards" or similar. "My best regard" would not make sense as regard can not be a singular noun.

Imagine writing, "Yours incerely" at the end of a letter. It gives a bad impression.

Answer (score 1):

The suitor says "My *feelings* for you are genuine."

**Congratulations**! The girl believes him.

The **news** is that they are to be married soon.

The king sends his **regards**.

**Toward (AE) / Towards (BE) a Better Understanding.**

The letter/sound "S" is very powerful in English. So, be mindful when you run into one. It could mean the difference between: HE and SHE. MR and MRS.

No wonder your **BOSS** doesn't want you to go around dropping "Ss". Next thing you know,     you'll be calling the boss, **BO**, an anglicized form of **beau**, boyfriend.

Tongue-in-cheek? Yes. But, you should get the point. And that is what counts!